# ! LaTeX3 Error: Command '\FA' already defined!

Tags: compiling, fontawesome, compilation-error, awesome-cv

I used the following template for my CV :https://www.latextemplates.com/template/awesome-resume-cv. I can build it on Overleaf, but not with Textworks. I've specified to use Xelatex as compiler.

This is the output that I get with Textworks:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Command '\FA' already defined!

For immediate help type H <return>.

     ...                                              

    l.166 \newfontfamily
                        \headerfont[
    ? H

    You have used \NewDocumentCommand with a command that already has a
    definition.

    The existing definition of '\FA' will not be altered.

    ?
```

And here is the log file : https://pastebin.com/HB2zeXs8.
Can someone help me?
Thanks for the help,

Warok

Comment: I didn't see this post, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yeah, it solve the problem thanks